# grab the word in a url using jquery?

Tags: jquery, string

i have a url that will be consistent in this format:

http://www.name.com/heart/game/2012/topics/SOMETHINGHERE.html

I need to grab the 'SOMETHINGHERE' after topics/ and use that as a variable.  I can get the current url:

```
var currentUrl = $(location).attr('href');
```

but not sure how to target and get just "SOMETHINGHERE" part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the url into parts based on the slashes and then remove the .html from the end of the last part of the url:

```
var currentUrl = $(location).attr('href');
var urlParts = currentUrl.split( "/" );

var something = urlParts[urlParts.length-1].substr( 0, urlParts[urlParts.length-1].lastIndexOf( ".html" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the URL structure, you could use a regular expression:

```
var pathname = location.pathname; // '/heart/game/2012/topics/SOMETHINGHERE.html'
pathname.match(/\/topics\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html/)[1]; // 'SOMETHINGHERE'
```

To avoid throwing errors on pages that don’t match this URL pattern, you could use [the `.match()` trick](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/match-trick/):

```
var pathname = location.pathname; // '/some/url/that/doesnt/match/this/pattern.html'
(pathname.match(/\/topics\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html/) || [, ''])[1]; // ''
```

Note that you shouldn’t use `$(location).attr('href')` — use `location.href` instead. In this case, I’d use `location.pathname` as you don’t need the scheme or the domain name at all.